# HTTPS with iFrame that is also HTTPS

Tags: http, iframe, https

OK i am not sure if what i am trying to do is even possible.

We have a page that is HTTPS, and it has a fancybox that opens an iFrame that is also HTTPS. But the iframe wont load.

Now if i take the originating page and remove the HTTPS from the URL and load the fancy box the iframe that is HTTPS will now load.

So my question is can HTTPS page load a HTTPS iframe? If it is possible do you need special code to do so?

Also worth noting that if i remove the fancy box from the equation i get the same results.

Comment: Is the iframe loading an HTTPS page in the same domain as the parent HTTPS page?

Comment: @RemyLebeau They are 2 separate domains we are using 2 well known apps (CRM and Ecommerce) and we want them to be seamless to the end user, which is why we are using an iframe from inside our CRM to display a small ecommerce store

Comment: That is subject to cross-domain security restrictions, which would explain why it is not working.

Comment: Is there anyway around this? @RemyLebeau i am not very good on the sever side of things

Comment: Maybe. If you have control over the server and can add custom HTTP headers, you can try adding `Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers to the main page so the browser knows the iframe is allowed to load content from another domain that is trusted, thus [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) is satisfied.

Comment: Hey Thanks for all the info @RemyLebeau It is certainly somewhere to start.